# Windows 10 start menu don't work

Tags: windows-10

After some installation (JRE, eclipse, VirtualBox), my start menu don't work any more.

When I click it, nothing is happening. And modern apps doesnt work either.

I tried revert my installation but the problem still present.

Also, I try this: http://www.urtech.ca/2015/05/solved-windows-10-start-menu-and-modern-apps-do-not-function/

I do up to step 4 because I would not waste my softwares...

But nothing of this step fix my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using system restore to revert your windows to before you installed or did you just uninstall Java using the control panel?

Comment: just uninstall Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find a solution of my issue:

1. Create a temporary admin user
2. Copie files in the temporary user directorie
3. Remove your user
4. Create a new user with microsoft account
5. Copie files in your new user
6. Remove the temporary user

If don't use a microsoft account just create a new user.

This solution fix the problem for me.

I hope it can help someone.